# is protractor or browser prefered when testing a large angular application

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have used browser and ptor in my previous tests, and they have different issues, but overall both seem buggy, although I like browser better.

So my question is, for testing a large angular application, is it more preferred to use the protractor.getInstance or just using regular browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser object and the object returned by protractor.getInstance() are the same object.

```
console.log("compare " + (protractor.getInstance() === browser));
```

prints "compare true"

It doesn't matter which you use, except stylistically.  I like the browser object better.

For the non-wrapped webdriver instance, use browser.driver.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I did not realize this until I tested this myself just now! Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: so i know its mentioned that ptor is constructed off browser, does that mean ptor is the bigger player here?

Comment: @user2167582 It doesn't matter which one you use since they are the same object. I would just use browser because it's more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. **EDIT:** Per alan.myrvold, `browser` and `protractor.getInstance()` are actually the exact same object. I didn't realize this until I verified his comment just now. Therefore you can use either one.

Note that if you are testing a NON-angular app, you must use browser.driver or `protractor.getInstance().driver` which is a webdriver instance. Using protractor.getInstance() or browser will throw errors because it will try to search for angular.

Answer (score -2):

It's a very general question.

The angular community right now seems to move to Protractor, which is WebdriverJS based and - as far as I can tell - pretty powerful. The gist behind it is, that it *uses* regular browsers to do automated testing for you.

However, Protractor is a very young project and it requires a bit of getting used to. I myself found it a bit buggy and not yet suited to my needs.

Second point is: Do both. Do not completely rely on (integration) tests. You should always test functionality by hand - and should have it tested by someone else. After all, your computer is not a human.

Lastly, there is no definite answer, and I do not think it belongs here - we're here to help with specific programming problems.

Comment: thanks, I was just wondering if protractor.getInstance() was ready to do what browser did in angular e2e tests.

Comment: depends on what you want exactly - a quick look at the protractor source (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L11) reveals the capabilities with elements implemented. I'd say the options in karma are a bit better (but i usually resort to trigger events via `angular.element`).